# Package/Bundle .NET 4.0 (MVC Framework)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I've been asked to develop some .NET based websites to site on client web servers.

The solution I develop needs to work on as many .NET platforms as possible.
Therefore it really needs to work on 2.0 and will (by default) work on 3.0, 3.5, 4, etc.

This is to cater for clients who "cannot" upgrade from .NET 2.0.

The issue is, for speed and flexibility, I want to use the MVC framework which requires 3.5+.

So, does anyone know if there are any solutions that allow you to 'bundle' up all the required .NET 3.5 components so that the solution can essentially run "stand alone" without requiring any installed software/framework (aside 2.0 at the very least).

(I'm pretty sure the answer is no, since .NET ins an integral part of Windows, plus its huge, so 'bundling' it will be a massive/impossible task - but there might just be a commercial solution out there...?)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Wix.
This may do just what you are looking for:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm
How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper